# VBA: Workbooks.Save & Close not saving

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that is working but the line .close closes the WB without saving:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function updateStatus(fpath As String, fname As String, num As String)

Dim wk As String, yr As String
Dim owb As Workbook
Dim trow As Variant

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath & fname)

trow = owb.Sheets(1).Range("Change" & num).Row
owb.Sheets(1).Cells(trow, 5).value = "Test"

With owb
    .Save
    .Close SaveChanges:=True 'This line doesn't seem to work
End With

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Function
```

If I remove the line, the WB stays open and I see the change. If I add the line, and open the specific file, I see no change.

Comment: remote the `with Application` lines at the top of the sub (comment them out) and see if a warning is shown.

Comment: There is no warning if I remove the lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the code looks ok, you probably have some Data Protection enabled on your Excel, which does not allow the saving. Try to make a **minimal example** like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim owb As Workbook

    Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\vityata\Desktop\Testing.xlsx")
    owb.Save
    owb.Close

End Sub
```

Then debug with `F8` and see the message that you got, once you go pass by `owb.Save`.

Just that you know:

```
.Save
.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

With the `.Save` line you make the `SaveChanges:=True` part useless. And vice versa.

Comment: Debug with F8 was the perfect hint - I found a script running when opening the workbook that overrides what the prior script wrote. After removing/changing the scirpt, it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try .Activate before executing the .Save command. That has worked for me in the same situation.